# How to save a model in json in yii2?

Tags: json, model, yii2

I have a model like follow:

```
$book = \backend\models\Book::find()->all();
```

then I can access to special column value by follow statement:

```
$ID = $book[0]['ID'];
```

Now I want to convert this model to Json and save it in DB. therefore I've write bellow code:

```
$json = json_encode($book);
```

then I want to load and decode it.

```
$object = json_decode($json) ;
$ID = $object[0]['ID'];
```

but I can't. I don't know what should I do for this purpose. is it possible that convert a model to json?

can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Attach json to the question, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for all answers. I wanted to save all model as a json or string in DB and then retrive it and use as a model again. so I've solved this problem by `serialize()`

```
$book = \backend\models\Book::find()->all();
$str = serialize($book);
$object = unserialize($str);
$ID = $object[0]['ID'];
```

Answer (score 2):

json_decode converts data to StdObject by default. If you want to work with an array instead of an object, you should set `assoc` parameter to `true`

```
$object = json_decode($json, true) ;
$ID = $object[0]['ID'];
```

If your json is empty then you must configure `[fields][1]` method to correct data export. For example:

```
class Book extends ActiveRecord
{
    // some code

    public function fields()
    {
        return [
            'id',
            // others attributes of Book model
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. but it doesn't work because when I use `$json = json_encode($book);` and then `die(var_dump($hson))` it returns some empty arrays: `D:\Project Files\Git\SAME\backend\controllers\NewRequestController.php:60:string '[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]' (length=34)`. problem is in encoding of model to json.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$book = \backend\models\Book::find()->asArray()->all();
$json = json_encode($book);
$data = json_decode($json, true);
print_r($data[0]['ID']);
```

Add `->asArray()` when querying